# Creating a regex expression

Tags: regex

I'm using regex to block user agents on a website. I have created this regex, I'm new to them but if I'm right in thinking, this will block every user agent that is blank?

```
^((?!/[a-zA-Z0-9]/).*)$
```

Would love the help guys, thank you.

Comment: This regular expression seems bizzare for agent strings. It will reject `/a/foo`, but will not reject `/aa/foo`, or `//foo` or much else. Are you sure this is what you want?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a regex here, why not just check if the user agent string is `null`, `empty`, `""`, or `0`?

If this is for an .htaccess type of thing, you could always try this type of regex:

```
^$
```